# XACML on Android

Tags: android, xacml

I have to read some XACML file on an Android device. I have searched on Google and I have found only the [Sun's XACML](http://sunxacml.sourceforge.net/) which is not supposed to work in Android

Is there some library that I can use?

Comment: I'm interested in what the use-case might be. Do you have to read an XACML policy or an XACML request?

Comment: Hey @martijno, sorry for the late reply. I had to read XACML policy, but finally I have used Simple XML to read the xml file and parse it. Have you found a different approach?

Comment: Not really. Was merely triggered by the combination Android + XACML and was wondering what you're trying to implement... Apparently you're doing policy evaluation (i.e. the PDP) on a mobile device? Or policy administration?

Answer (score 1):

As of 2014, there aren't any XACML engines for Android.

If your use case is merely to parse XACML policies but not evaluate them, the approach you took (to use an XML parser) is the best one yet.

The XACML TC is considering defining a JSON notation for XACML policies. Stay tuned for updates.

Comment: Hey Folks, 

Did any progress happened on XACML engines ?

Comment: Yes! Axiomatics released a one-jar engine which you can run anywhere you can run Java